# Failed to create environments: browserIDE Cloud9 could not connect to the EC2 instance. Please check your VPC configuration and network settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc, cloud9

New with AWS here, i want to create a cloud9 environment but i´m receiving this error:

> Failed to create environments: browserIDE Cloud9 could not connect to the EC2 instance. Please check your VPC configuration and network settings. Go to CloudFormation stack

I read the [vpc requirements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/vpc-settings.html) to create a cloud9 environment and found this [tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/05/30/aws-create-a-vpc-with-public-and-private-subnets-and-a-nat-gateway) to create a vpc, i configured the NAT gateway, the route tables and the internet gateways but i am receiving the error

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just download this cloud9 [template](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-cloud9-ide/blob/d31fd5728b8518dc1cc8802fa98770f3b5498bd7/templates/cloud9-ide-master.template.yaml) to create a cloud 9 instance using with cloudformation stack, is important to select the option to prevent the rollback.

It has some errors but at least a cloud9 instance works, if you receive an error please check the original [github repo](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-cloud9-ide) and the [guidelines](https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-cloud9-ide/doc/aws-cloud9-cloud-based-ide.pdf)

Comment: So what was the problem exactly? "Just use this other template" doesn't bring any clarity on what the problem was.

Comment: Idk, I give up and ended using a template to solve the problem, it was like 4 months ago‍♀️

Comment: Thanks for replying to my comment, but objectively speaking the "answer" isn't really an answer to the question. It's just a record of what you did _instead_ of finding the answer. As such I'm going to down-vote the answer. I feel that it would be better placed as simply a comment to the question, because it doesn't really answer anything.